# Ошибка загрузки Grub 2

Tags: ubuntu, grub

Устанавливаю elementaryOS на ПК с флешки. Установка прошла успешно (разбил разделы, все в норме), кроме установки Grub, он ругался, что не может быть установлен на данный диск. Продолжил без него, после завершения установил вручную. При загрузке получаю такой экран.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем проблема? Спасибо.

Comment: *В чем проблема?* — очевидно в этом: *не может быть установлен на данный диск… установил вручную*

Comment: А что не так? Я, полазив по форумам, заметил, что такое случается и вручную потом многие устанавливают.

Comment: Как усанавливал вручную?

Comment: Через livecd: sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda